# Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [453372] from [/my_filter]: std::bad_alloc

Tags: ros, c++, rviz, ros-melodic, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to publish PCL point clouds which are obtained from velodyne point cloud. The program is compiled and running. I can even see the height and width information from the PCL point clouds but when I open RVIZ and visualize the published PCL point clouds, I get this message.

> [ERROR] [1602489936.969819842]:
> Exception thrown when deserializing
> message of length [453372] from
> [/my_filter]: std::bad_alloc

```
ros::Publisher ptc_pub;
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image, const PointCloud2ConstPtr& pt_cloud)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> pcl_cloud;
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*pt_cloud, pcl_cloud);
  int PCLwidth = pcl_cloud.width;
  int PCLheight = pcl_cloud.height;
  cout<< "width = "<<PCLwidth <<endl;
  cout<< "height"<<PCLheight <<endl;
  ptc_pub.publish(pcl_cloud);
  // ros::spinOnce();
  // loop_rate.sleep();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_filter");
  ros::NodeHandle node_;

  ros::Publisher ptc_pub = node_.advertise<PointCloud>("pcl_pts", 1);
  // ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> img_sub(node_, "cam_1/color/image_raw", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<PointCloud2> pointcloud_sub(node_, "velodyne_points", 1);


  typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<Image, PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10),img_sub, pointcloud_sub);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1,_2));
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

What I am doing wrong ? My guess is that I have placed the publisher wrong or is it something else ? I am new to ROS and cpp. Any suggestion will be really useful.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363227/exception-thrown-when-deserializing-message-of-length-%5B453372%5D-from-%5B/my_filter%5D:-std::bad_alloc/) by [aravindsaiUR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60815/aravindsaiur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you guessed, the type of the variable you are giving to the publisher is different; it will convert to sensor_msgs::PointCloud instead of pcl::PointCloud, so try the following

```
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image, const PointCloud2ConstPtr& pt_cloud)
{
  PointCloud pt_cloud1;
  convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud(*pt_cloud, pt_cloud1);
  ptc_pub.publish(pt_cloud1);
}
```

ref: [convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs.html#ab4620a23b181e9fe9d24181e4bc1eb8c)

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aravindsaiUR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60815/aravindsaiur/) on 2021-05-19**:
You're right. That was the issue. Thanks :)

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-05-19**:
You're welcome.